# Sort documents in Kentico 9 Document Library Widget

Tags: sorting, kentico, document-library

We are using the Kentico 9 Document Library Widget to display a list of files in a folder. But what I cannot find is a way to set the sort order of the files being displayed seems to be random.

Do I have to customize the widget to have to do a sort based on a date field for example?

Comment: Could you please be more specific...there is no such widget in a default kentico installation: http://i.imgur.com/zlxT53g.jpg Are you sure this is not a custom component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make **ORDER BY** property **visible** in *Widgets* application. You can set default value or set proper ordering in widget properties dialog.

[image]

Note to Boris: Document libary is one of the [abandoned features](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Recovering+abandoned+features,+web+parts+and+widgets) in v9.